# How can I query projects that were completed after or between certain dates?

Tags: api, activecollab

I'm using the ActiveCollab API to query projects.  I'd like to query recently completed projects.  Is there a way I can use the "completed_on" field to query multiple dates?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can run a projects report instead of regular projects archive. Here's an example API URL:

https://your-activecollab.com/api/v1/reports/run?created_on_filter=any&completed_on_filter=selected_range_2019-05-01%3A2019-05-01&type=ProjectsFilter&include_all_projects=true

Notice the `completed_on_filter` argument and that it specifies a date range.

Comment: Thanks but I'm using the latest API.  How do I convert that command into a call using PHP?  i.e. 

`$query = $client->get('projects?sort_by_name=1&is_completed=1&completed_on=' . $yesterday);`

Comment: ActiveCollab support - any update on this?  The query you provided isn't working.